# Pre-login session id?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, authentication, jsessionid

I have a simple webapp on Tomcat with form authentication, and notice that there is a "pre-login" JSESSIONID that's being set whenever a user just *goes* to the login page, *before any login attempt even occurs*.

Is this default behavior in Tomcat? Why does Tomcat generate a JSESSIONID just for *loading* a login page? Shouldn't it generate any session id's **only** after an actual login? (Not because someone just *loads* the login page!)

Note: I should mention that my *entire* webapp (login page and all) is hosted over https; no part of it is exposed via http. Also I am **not using** JSP. After login, Tomcat generates a *second* JSESSIONID, different from the first. And that's the one the user uses for the remainder of their session.

But **why** does it set a "pre-login" JSESSIONID *in the first place?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Tomcat means of form auth, it has to store the initial request somewhere to perform the stateless redirect for the auth. After that, it will re-evaluate the request. The [`SavedRequest`](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/FormAuthenticator.java#FormAuthenticator.saveRequest%28org.apache.catalina.connector.Request%2Corg.apache.catalina.Session%29) is saved in the [session](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/FormAuthenticator.java#191). You should disable the [`changeSessionIdOnAuthentication`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Form_Authenticator_Valve) flag.

Comment: I'm aware JSPs create a session by default, and I am *not* using JSPs!

Comment: @ManRow, I have changed my answer.

Comment: Ahh, so just to clarify, the "SavedRequest" is just the request a user was trying to make before the server presented him/her a login screen? So then, if I understand correctly, the login screen will then post to `j_security_check`, and the server will then honor a successful login attempt by forwarding to the user's "SavedRequest" ?

Comment: @ManRow, yes you can check the links provided and you'll see that.