# Web application server does not create session

Tags: java, session, tomcat, jsessionid

I'm using tomcat as a web application server for a simple java webapp.
I noticed that tomcat does not create any Session when I log in. As a consequence, I don't get any `JSESSIONID` cookie (neither visible in Chrome or Firefox)

If I try calling `request.getSession(false)` within `doGet` or `doPost` methods, it returns `null`. BUT, once I call `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)`, a session is created and I get `JSESSIONID` cookie.

I cannot figure out why tomcat does not create a session immediatly for my webapp.

One other intersting element: I can deploy a second java webapp (almost similar to my first one) and this one receives a valid session immediatly after login, without having to call `request.getSession()`. Both application use basic authentication and I cannot find evident difference that explains the different behaviour.

Any idea why tomcat creates a session for one app and not for the other one ?

Thanks

---

EDIT

Well, after investigation (step by step debug of tomcat) I could see that tomcat forwards request to error page, which is defined as `<error-page>` entry in the `web.xml` of my second app. The session appears after forwarding to this error page.

My conclusion is that by default tomcat does not create any session nor `JSESSIONID` cookie on basic auth. A session is created once tomcat has to load a jsp form, which can be either a login form or an error page. The jsp page initialization explicitely invoke the `getSession()` method. Here's the code of `PageContextImpl.inizialize()` (available [here, line 130](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.x/java/org/apache/jasper/runtime/PageContextImpl.java)):

```
// Setup session (if required)
if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest && needsSession) {
    this.session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
}
```

Therefore my opinion is that the only garantee to have an existing session is to get (or create) one explicitely in servlet by invoking `request.getSession()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20213301/61158

Comment: Not really. I'm not using form login, just basic auth.

Comment: Well actually maybe yes... I changed basic auth to form and then I received a JSESSIONID and a session. 
So I guess tomcat does not deliver a session for basic auth, except if explicitly requested via `request.getSession()`. I also guess somehow my second app is requesting a session that way...